# Use search function on a Laravel collection of objects to return the key?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

Generally speaking, I am trying to remove an object from a laravel collection of objects.   I do not wish to convert the collection to an array to do this task, as this invalidates any real reason to use collections in the first place.  Nor do I wish to delete the underlying model from the database - I just wish to remove the record from the collection.

Looking at the docs for available methods I don't see a simple way to complete this task.

Laravel Collections have a [variety of methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods).  The [search method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-search) looks very promising,

> The search method searches the collection for the given value and returns its key if found.

I was planning to use the returned key with the [forget method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forget) to dispose of the unwanted object.

> The forget method removes an item from the collection by its key

However, every example I can find for the "search" method uses only a simple collection of integers or strings to show functionality.  I am looking to search within the objects included in the collection.

We have the following variables:

```
$coll // a collection of objects taken from a database.  
            // Each object contains a field called "invoice_number" that I am trying to match.

$invoice_number // the invoice number associated with the object
                // I wish to remove from $coll

$tmp_object = $coll->firstWhere('invoice_number', $invoice_number);  // the needle for the haystack
```

Any assistance in finding a solution to the problem using collections is appreciated, especially using the "search" method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the "filter" method :

```
$coll = $coll->filter(function($invoice) use ($invoice_number){
return $invoice->invoice_number != $invoice_number;
});
```

if your invoice_number is unique, you can do this :

```
$coll = $coll->keyBy('invoice_number');

$coll[$invoice_number];
```

to retrieve it and

```
$coll->forget($invoice_number);
```

to only remove it from your collection

Comment: Most elegant solution uses keyBy, though it's necessary to reassign $coll like `$coll = $coll->keyBy('invoice_number')->forget($invoice_number)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter):

```
$res = $coll->filter(function($el) use($invoice_number){
    return $el->invoice_number != $invoice_number;
});
```